# Turn by turn navigation GPX file app

Tags: iphone, applications, gps, navigation

We wanna start doing car rallys and these routes are delivered using a GPX files.

What we are looking for is an app that can make a route from our home to the start of the gpx file and then start navigating the GPX route.

Answer (score 1):

**[Gpx Navigator](http://www.gpxnavigator.com)**

> 1. Getting Started. GPX Navigator gives you a powerful, great way to navigate yourself through your own custum routes routes. GPX Navigater includes useful features like follow yourself on map or use the special navigation board to see where is the next GPS point of your journey.
> 2. Create your own GPX file. Use free, online solutions to create your own files and plan your trips. Bike Hike Cruise Creator The Hug
> 3. Import your files to GPX Navigator. You can easily add your GPX files to GPX Navigator, using iTunes File Sharing (in Apps tab). iTunes File Sharing

**[GPX-Viewer](https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/id880510678?mt=8)**

> Import and view GPS eXchange format (GPX) files. GPX-Viewer views GPX files exported from many GPS devices and other apps that create GPX files.
>
> Import the files using iTunes file sharing, your Dropbox account, eMail, an URL, or for iOS8 and above, from iCloud.
>
> - Download files to your device for offline viewing.
> - Chart elevation vs. track points or distance.
> - Send the waypoints to Apple Maps.
> - Email the file.
> - Create folders to better organize your GPX files.
> - Set different location tracking modes.
> - Selected routes show as a different color to easily visualize.
> - Hide or show the waypoints on the map.
> - View track points on map.
> - Track points show distances and other values.

Comment: I've tried GPX Navigator but the interface of TomTom Navigation spoiled me.